# How to close temporary(anonymous) File object passed in as parameter?

Tags: ruby, file-io

Sometimes I found myself need to open a file, read it content and do some functional manipulation and store the data to an variable. This would end up with the following line of code:

```
@some_vars = File.open("items.txt").read.chomp!.split(',')
```

I have two questions here:

- Does the File instance `File.open()` closed after this line?
- How to close such a File instance without sacrificing the readability?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, [`File.open`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File.html#method-c-open) leaves the file handle open. You should use [`IO.read`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-c-read) instead, which returns the entire contents of the file and closes it when it's done:

```
IO.read("items.txt").chomp!.split(',')
```

This is bit shorter for one-liners than passing a block to `File.open`.

Comment: Are you sure? I thought `File` is a subclass of `IO` and inherits the `read` method from it.

Comment: `IO.read` and `File.read` are the same, but `read` isn't a documented method in `File` so it's less confusing to link to and reference the one in `IO`.

Comment: +1 because it's more readable as a one-liner than the block syntax I suggested, although I definitely think the block is the right way to go in the general case. IO#read is essentially a slurp, with all the pluses and minuses that entails. Everything's a trade-off. :)

Answer (score 1):

The example you posted will not close the file descriptor automatically. You would have to manually call File#close on the descriptor, or let Ruby close the file automatically when the interpreter exits.

If you want to automatically close a file, you need the [File#open block syntax](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File.html#method-c-open):

```
File.open('items.txt') { |f| f.read.chomp!.split(',') }
```

Ruby will then close the file whenever the block terminates.

Answer (score 0):

Even using block in `File.open` doesn't make sure that file will be always closed, for example, when the application is suspended.
There's a trick to protect from this kind of situation.

```
f = File.open('items.txt', 'w')

at_exit { f.flush; f.close }
```

Then `at_exit` block will be executed at the end of application or when the program exits.

Comment: Err, can you provide a working example for this? `File.open`'s block syntax uses `ensure` underneath, which I don't think will ever fail to run when `at_exit` would succeed.

Comment: If the interpreter exits, the OS will close all open file handles anyway.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall, I used this trick only once and it was the requirement from organizer of the competition, you can see this usage here https://gist.github.com/be91b8e176f85326e656

Comment: I dunno, I'm not convinced. A simple test shows that `ensure` is run even when SIGINT or SIGTERM is sent to the program. Using `at_exit` instead of the block seems unnecessary and unclear. Further, all file handles will be released at exit by default anyway, the whole point of closing them manually is that they're freed as soon as possible.